# MongoDB Server Shows OpenSSL's Different Version than Installed

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, version, mongodb

On Ubuntu Machine, Installed OpenSSL Version is :

> Used Command : **openssl version**

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
```

But, MongoDB Version Shows OpenSSL Version as :

> Used Command : **mongod --version**

```
db version v3.4.2
git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Why Both Versions are different ?

Output of `ldd /usr/bin/mongod` is as follows :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd13ff5000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f9c660e8000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f9c65d0c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9c65b04000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9c65900000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9c655fa000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9c653e4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9c651c6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9c64e01000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9c6909c000)
```

Comment: Could be statically linked, or you could have two library versions installed. Running `ldd` on the mongo binary should offer some clues

Comment: @jordanm How should I run `ldd` on Mongodb ?

Comment: `ldd /path/to/mongod`